# VirtualPathProviderViewEngine triggers add migration error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a solution split into different projects, with a shared one called `MyProject.Shared` containing common classes.

Inside this project, whenever I create a class that inherits from `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` I am not able to run `Add-Migration` anymore as it fails with a `Could not load file or assembly MyProject.Shared`.

If I delete the file containing the `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` subclass the add migration command will run smoothly. How is this possible?

EDIT: The same happens if I try to inherit from `IVewEngine`.

Comment: Same thing here, it cannot find my shared assembly.

Comment: are you using asp.net core? I have some issues adding `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` to the project. I wanted to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was resolved for me after `dotnet restore`ing to a different target, then back again. Perhaps it cleared some cache somewhere.

More specifically, I changed the RuntimeIdentifier in the csproj, `dotnet restore`d, then removed the RuntimeIdentifier, and `dotnet restore`d again.